OpenConnect VPN Server and DNSMasq DNS Server on Same Machine
I am running an OpenConnect VPN server on a Debian 11 machine. The VPN server works perfectly when configured to use Google public DNS, but I want to run my own DNS server on the same machine and use it for OpenConnect DNS. I am using DNSMasq for this.
My DNSMasq config is:
no-resolv
no-hosts
server=8.8.4.4
server=8.8.8.8

Which runs DNSMasq on localhost port 53 on all network interfaces (since no interfaces are specified) and forwards requests upstream to Google public DNS.
In /etc/init.d/dnsmasq, I remove the --local-service flag from DNSMASQ_OPTS to allow requests from a non-local network.
I also disabled systemd-resolved.
This is the result of running dig google.com @127.0.0.1 on the machine with OpenConnect and DNSMasq (you can see it has been cached by DNSMasq, so DNSMasq is working):
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             265     IN      A       142.250.191.110

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 22 10:32:59 CDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

But when I configure OpenConnect server to use 127.0.0.1 for DNS (and verified this change is applied by running occtl show user <my username>, I cannot load websites when connected to the VPN from a different machine. I can still connect to the VPN.
I do not use UFW or any other firewall package, only IPTables. IPTables rules:
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT


SOLUTION:
This worked for me after playing around with configs.
In /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf, find what value you are using for ipv4-network, suppose it's 192.168.5.0 (with some netmask set in ipv4-netmask).
In /etc/dnsmasq.conf, set listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,192.168.5.1
Then in /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf, set dns=192.168.5.1
Restart DNSMasq and OCServ.
You should keep --local-service in /etc/init.d/dnsmasq. Shouldn't need to modify /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/hosts at all.
